# How do to see day when you access a site?

Tags: firefox, history

I enter a site last year, using firefox for that, `ex: www.somesite.com`

In the history <kbd>Ctrl + h</kbd> I can to see that entry to the site, but I can not see the date, when I enter

In the history of the last few days, I can see by date, but that site appears in **previous 6 months**

I need know the **exact day**. Is there any way to see at the history of firefox?

I use windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, 
It is a way to get what you're asking. I hope you serve.

You need to use `Ctrl+Shift+H`, right click and 
more recent visits

[Solution](https://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/951491)

Comment: Two questions, same link, one quoted the material one didn't.  Guess which one will be helpful when the link no longer works like what happens to every other Mozilla link.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox history is stored in your Firefox profile on your computer in an SQLite database called `places.sqlite` which can be opened using an SQLite reader.

It may give you the information you require.

[Mozilla support page for Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)

> How do I find my profile?
>
> Click the menu button, click **Help** and select **Troubleshooting Information**. The **Troubleshooting Information** tab will open.
>
> Under the **Application Basics** section, click on **Show Folder**. A window with your profile files will open.